# Benchmarking SpMV C Code

Tags: c, codeblocks, benchmarking, sparse-matrix

I've been assigned to report test results of an [SpMV](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=Sparse+matrix+vector+multiplication) algorithm, something I've never done before.

I came to ask:

- What program should I use to benchmark the code, is there one that produces a graph?
- Which sizes should I test for, besides the maximum? Are there sizes that will make irregularities with the cache and produce different results even though the size difference is 1? (Different time for 512x512 and 513x513 or 1023x1023 and 1024x1024).
- I could use the *time.h* library but is table of time of exec. and matrix sizes enough?

I'm on Windows.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably there are sizes that work particularly well on your machine, but it is very hard to predict which size that might be. That is why you should test a lot of different sizes, i.e. it's best to make a loop in your code and output the results to a file and plot it (execution time vs size).

For each size you have you should execute the SpMV function several times and compute the mean time from that, because it takes time to load the matrices and vectors into cache from memory. Once they are already there the execution is probably a lot faster.

For time measurements you could use something like

```
#include <sys/time.h>    
void tic(){ gettimeofday( &start, NULL);}

void toc(){ gettimeofday( &stop, NULL);}

double diff(){ return (stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + 1e-6*(stop.tv_usec - start.tv_usec);}
```

There are profilers for C-code on windows but they take some time to learn.  (I myself work on linux, so I can't recommend a particular one)